# Usage of Verb て Verb て

Tags: grammar, verbs

I am currently studying the usage of Verb て Verb て sentence structure which means that I have two te form verbs being used in a sentence. I just need a bit of clarification.

For example:

> I wake up at 6:00 AM, brush my teeth, and go to university on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday.

Would the sentence be...

> げつ、すい、きんは　ごぜんろくじに　おきて、はを　みがいて、だいがくへ　いくんです。

Comment: It looks like you have a number of unrelated questions here. It would be better for you to ask them in separate posts, so that people can answer each of them separately.

Comment: yeah sure... I'll split it up.

Comment: Fixed...and I just earned a badge XD!

Comment: Please use a couple of more commas.  This is an eye-killer.

Comment: I added commas and spaces to help with reading this text, since it's written entirely in kana.  (I'm not sure how げつ、すい、きん should be written in kana―are those commas normal?)

Comment: Yes, that's the correct usage of the comma in this case

Comment: @snailboat entirely in kana? What does that mean? I even see "write as you're speaking in kana" on my worksheets.

Comment: @usukidoll Japanese is usually written in a kana-kanji mixture.  The kanji help you visually break the text up into words.  Of course, you can write Japanese without kanji!  You'll find children's books written that way, for example.  But those children's books often use spaces to make it easier to read, so I thought spaces might be helpful here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your use of the -て is correct.